# What is the pdf for this ordered statiatic?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, solution-verification

The independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$. Each $X_i$~$U([0,1])$ (I.e. uniform distribution on the $[0,1]$)

$V = \min$ $\{ X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 \}$ and $W = \max\{ X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 \}$.

Find the joint probability density function $f(v,w)$ for two variables $V$ and $W$

$(sol)$ I'm focusing the case $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq  x_4 $

$$F(u,v) =P( W\leq w  ,V    \leq  v )= 24 \int_0^{w} \int_0^{v} \int_0^{x_4} \int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}d{x
_1 }d{x_4} = 4vw^3 - 6v^2w^2$$

The reason  why  multiplying the 24  is there are  24 arangements by the order for   $x_1$ to $x_4 $ including my case $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq  x_4 $.

Hence $f(v,w)=\frac{\partial ^2 F}{\partial v\partial w }=12w^2-24vw$ for$ 0<v<w<1$

But the answer was $12(w-v)^2$

What were mistakes in my solution? In my guess the integration domain is false. But I can't find which point I was wrong.

re-editing) From the integration domain,  $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq  x_4 $

I'm focusing on the $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3$ $\Rightarrow$ $\color{red}\int_\color{red}{x_1}^\color{red}{x_3} \color{red}d\color{red}{x_2}$

Next since the order of the $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ are determined, Just consider the $x_3 \leq x_4$ $\Rightarrow$ $\color{blue}\int_\color{blue}0^\color{blue}{x_4} \color{red}\int_\color{red}{x_1}^\color{red}{x_3} \color{red}d\color{red}{x_2}\color{blue}d\color{blue}{x_3}$

Next consider the domain of the $x_1$ and $x_4$

Hence, $\int_0^{w} \int_0^{v} \int_0^{x_4} \int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}d{x_1}d{x_4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ P(W\leq w  ,V    \leq  v ) \ne 24 \int_0^{w} \int_0^{v} \int_0^{x_4} \int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}d{x
_1 }d{x_4}$ because $P(X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3 \le X_4, X_1 \le w, X_4 \le v) \ne \int_0^{w} \int_0^{v} \int_0^{x_4} \int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}d{x
_1 }d{x_4}$.
The integration domain is $\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)| x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le x_4, x_1 \le w, x_4 \le v\}$ and it's not the integration domain that you used. For example, $x_3$ should be not bigger than $x_4$ and you supposed that $x_4 \in [x_1, x_3]$.

Addition: you wrote $ \int_0^{w} \int_0^{v} \color{blue}\int_\color{blue}0^\color{blue}{x_4} \color{red}\int_\color{red}{x_1}^\color{red}{x_3} \color{red}d\color{red}{x_2}\color{blue}d\color{blue}{x_3}d{x
_1 }d{x_4}$ and said: "from the red part $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3$". No, it doesn't follow. For example, we may have $\int_{0.3}^{0.2} dx_2$ in case when $x_1 = 0.3$ and $x_3 = 0.2$. And $\int_{0.3}^{0.2} dx_2 = -0.1$ but we should have only nonnegative values.

Comment: From the $x_3$'s domain($\int_0^{x_4}\int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}$) in my solutuion, does it already guarantee the$x_1 \leq x_2   \leq x_3 \leq x_4$?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang You wrote $\int_0^{w} \int_0^{v} \int_0^{x_4} \int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}d{x_1 }d{x_4}$. What did you mean? When you write $\int_a^b \int_c^d dx_1 dx_2$ do you imply that $x_1 \in [a,b]$ or $x_1 \in [c,d]$?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang anyway the domain of integration should be $\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)| x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le x_4, x_1 \le w, x_4 \le v\}$. If you use the right domain, you will get the right answer.

Comment: Sorry for unclear opinion. To clarify my opinion, I edited my post. Please confer the contents the below "edited. "

Comment: @se-hyuckyang, I made an addition. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes. It is clear :)

Comment: Would you suggest counter-example for the re-editing the post? This is the first thought when I tried this question.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang counter-example. You wrote: $$\int_0^{w} \int_0^{v} \int_0^{x_4} \int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}d{x_1}d{x_4}.$$ Put $u = w = 1$. In your domain of integration  $x_1$ and $x_4$ are arbitraty numbers in $[0,1]$. But in fact we should have $x_1 \le x_4$. Here's mistake. The analysis of your mistake is in addition to my answer. If you don't believe me, you may ask such a question on stackexch.: you may write $\int_0^{1} \int_0^{1} \int_0^{x_4} \int_{x_1}^{x_3} d{x_2}d{x_3}d{x_1}d{x_4}$ and ask: is that true that $x_1 \le x_4$ in the domain of intergaration. My answer is "obviously no".

Answer (score 3):

Your bounds must be determined by the support for the *ordered* statistics.$$\begin{align}F(v,w) &= 4!\iiiint_{0<x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<w, 0<x_1<v}\mathrm dx_4\,\mathrm dx_3\,\mathrm d x_2\,\mathrm dx_1\\&=24\int_0^v\int_{x_1}^w\int_{x_2}^w\int_{x_3}^w \mathrm d{x_4}\,\mathrm d{x_3}\,\mathrm d {x_2}\,\mathrm d{x_1}\quad\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant v\lt w\leqslant 1}\\[1ex]&=24\int_0^v\int_{x_1}^w\tfrac 12(w-x_2)^2\,\mathrm d x_2\,\mathrm d x_1\qquad\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant v\lt w\leqslant 1}\end{align}$$

---

[edit] Or in the order you tried

$$\small\begin{align}F(v,w) &= 24\int_0^w\int_{0}^{\min\{v,x_4\}}\int_{x_1}^{x_4}\int_{x_1}^{x_3} \mathrm d{x_2}\,\mathrm d{x_3}\,\mathrm d {x_1}\,\mathrm d{x_4}\\&=24~\left({{\int_0^v\int_0^{x_4}\int_{x_1}^{x_4}\int_{x_1}^{x_3}\mathrm d{x_2}\,\mathrm d{x_3}\,\mathrm d {x_1}\,\mathrm d{x_4}}+{\int_v^w\int_0^v\int_{x_1}^{x_4}\int_{x_1}^{x_3}\mathrm d{x_2}\,\mathrm d{x_3}\,\mathrm d {x_1}\,\mathrm d{x_4}}}\right)\\[1ex]&=24\left(\int_0^v\int_0^{x_4}\tfrac 12(x_4-x_1)^2\,\mathrm d x_1\,\mathrm d x_4+\int_v^w\int_0^{x_4}\tfrac 12(x_4-x_1)^2\,\mathrm d x_1\,\mathrm d x_4\right)\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively $f(v,w)= \dfrac{4!}{1!2!1!} (w-v)^2$ is intuitively the probability density for having one random variable at $v$, another at $w$, and the remaining two anywhere between those values.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. But I'm finding the my errors  for the integral's domain. As my quotes to Mr.(or Mrs) Botnakov N, I can't find my error in my integral's domain.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang  I have added an update for the integration order which you tried.  The integration domain for $x_1$ at a given $x_4$ is $[0{\ldots}\min\{v,x_4\}]$ , since we need to ensure $x_1$ is neither greater than $v$ nor $x_4$.  Thus this integration order requires us to partition the integral.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your solution. Let me propose propose the following one :

---

If $v\geq w$, then $\mathbb P\{W\leq w, V>v\}=0$. Suppose $0<v<w\leq 1$. Then, $$\mathbb P\{V>v, W\leq w\}=\mathbb P\{v\leq X_1\leq w\}^4=\left(\int_v^w\,\mathrm d x\right)^4=\left(w-v\right)^4.$$
Therefore,
$$\mathbb P\{V\leq v,W\leq w\}=\mathbb P\{W\leq w\}-\mathbb P\{ V>v,W\leq w\},$$ and thus,
$$f(v,w)=-\partial _{vw}\mathbb P\{ V>v,W\leq w\}=12(w-v)^2\boldsymbol 1_{\{0<v<w< 1\}}.$$

Comment: $P( W\leq w  ,V    \leq  v )=  P( W\leq w  ,V    \leq  v, X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3 \le X_4 ) + P( W\leq w  ,V    \leq  v, X_4 \le X_3 \le X_2 \le X_1 ) + \ldots    =  24 P( W\leq w  ,V    \leq  v, X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3 \le X_4 )$ by symmetry.  Further, $P( W\leq w  ,V    \leq  v, X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3 \le X_4 ) = P( X_4  \leq w  , X_1    \leq  v, X_1 \le X_2 \le X_3 \le X_4 )$ is found with the help of integration.